# How to convert ISO 8601 to USA Timezone

Tags: javascript, string, date, vue.js

I have a DateTime that I get from an API that looks like this 
2019-06-19T21:17:08.915Z
I believe it is called ISO 8601 but it does not have a user-friendly appearance. 
I want display it as formatted local date time.

For example, my current timezone looks like this 
5:20 PM
Wednesday, June 19, 2019 (EDT)

I tried to make something look similar to the one in the example.

I am using JavaScript and Vue.js. Is there a function I can use in the library to convert this DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manually set a timezone (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15141762/10221765)) - but this will automatically adjust to whichever timezone you're in:

```
console.log(new Date("2019-06-19T21:17:08.915Z"));
```

<sub>(doesn't produce correct output on SO)</sub>

Comment: Are you following me?

Comment: Yes @Choc13 - your answer doesn't produce the OP's exact required output, but it's the method I would have gone with.

Comment: You can set the timezone for a timestamp using [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with the timezone option, or one of many libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Does `new Date("2019-06-19T21:17:08.915Z").toLocaleString()` not do the trick?

Comment: The output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and may or may not include the local timezone, and may or may not include the timezone name.